# Create a Grid of Images -> Videos with Thumbnails

Tags: ios, swift, video, gridview, scrollview

I am designing an app and I want to have a grid of images. When an image is clicked it opens to another view that has a video player embedded and a text description underneath. How do I design a grid of images that opens to another view when tapped? So far, I have a grid, but it is only of images and the text is to right side of the image and I want the text directly under the image with some space between each other.

```
import SwiftUI



@available(iOS 14.0, *)

struct Content: View {

    var content = ["dog", "cat", "horse", "hamster", "parrot", "ferret"]

    let columns = [ GridItem(.flexible()), GridItem(.flexible()), GridItem(.flexible()), GridItem(.flexible())]

    var body: some View {

        ScrollView {

            LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {

                ForEach(content, id: \.self) { content in

                   Image(systemName: "keyboard")

                    .padding()

                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)

                    Text("\(content)")

                }

            }

        }

    }

}



struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {

    static var previews: some View {

        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {

            Content()

        } else {

            // Fallback on earlier versions

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: "I am designing an app and I want to have a grid of images." "How do I design a grid of image..."  That's not what the title of this topic says.

Comment: @ElTomato It's a grid of images that go to views with videos. I didn't think that it made that much of a difference.